# When I try to debug a pygame script I can't mouse click anything

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am writing a calculator program where you click on 'digit' rectangles to enter numbers. When I go into a debugger, mouse clicking doesn't register/ doesn't change any variables. I must be doing something obviously wrong. I've tried the idle debugger, the thonny debugger and the pycharm debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to attach some images or code, so we can evaluate your problem better. But, as far as I know, you need to update the Pygame display/frame each time you perform an action.

`pygame.display.update()`

This is a line to update Pygame display/frame. If you don't place this, the program will freeze.

Comment: I have gotten my program running by using many print statements to debug it. I didn't post it beause it it 460 lines long. And, indeed it uses pygame.display.update(). I just don't understand enough about debuggers to understand why they can't be used on these GUI programs.